# Use ngModel setViewValue from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I bind an array of values to a number of input elements. There are directives on the input elements, that set $parsers, $formatters and $validators. The controller should not care about the pipeline from viewValue to modelValue.

The view:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in main.values">
      <input ng-model="value.v" twice /> {{value.v}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Controller / Directive:

```
function MainController($scope) {
  this.values = [
    {v: 1}, {v: 2}, {v: 3}
  ];  
}

function twice() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(x) { return 2 * x });
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(x) { return 0.5 * x });
    }
  }  
}
```

I want to implement a copy & paste feature. The values in all the input elements should be overwritten from clipboard data. Therefore the controller implements a function which parses the clipboard data and sets the value for each input element. The values from clipboard are **view values**. Since the controller has no idea how to calculate **model values** from these view values, it has to use the '$parsers' pipeline from 'ngModelController'. How can I implement `MainController.paste()` to set the view value on each input element?

### Edit

I currently solved the actual problem (see comments) with a directive on the list element. http://plnkr.co/edit/9c2q2X?p=preview

```
function pasteValues() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
      elem.on('paste', function($event) {
        var data = $event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        var text = data.getData('Text');
        var values = text.split(' ');

        var inputs = elem.find('input');
        if (values.length === inputs.length) {
          for(var i = 0, e = values.length; i != e; ++i) {
            var input = inputs[i];
            var ngModel = angular.element(input).controller('ngModel');
            ngModel.$setViewValue(values[i]);
            input.value = values[i];
          }
          $event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: I actually think your approach is conceptually wrong. The controller only deals with model (i.e. View Model) values and should not be concerned with View values. "View values" belong to the concern of the View (i.e. DOM and directives).

Comment: @NewDev That's right, but where should I implement such a paste feature? A directive on the `ul` element should be good place. Something like `paste-values'... good comment... :)

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what `paste` should do? Does this simulate a copy-paste from the user? If so, the control that accepts the pasted value does its own transformation (i.e. `twice`) before the controller even gets a hold of it. Another way to think about it is to forget about the DOM/View/directives and just implement the controller (i.e. the app's logic) - what should the controller know about? Should there be a concept of `pasteHalfValue()`?

Comment: @NewDev The actual feature is to paste CSV data into a table of input elements. Each input element can receive the paste event, it doesn't matter. The controller (or a directive) has to parse the CSV data and fill the table. From your first comment I got the new idea to implement a directive on the table element that listen on `paste` instead of writing the handler in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I found two possible solutions (while writing the question:-)). http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNfYKTvSf6coGsohRlot?p=preview

### 1

The first is not really the angular way, because the controller has to know about DOM structure. But it is straighforward and doesn't need additional bindings and watches. To set the view value it uses the `angular.element.controller()` method to retrieve the ngModelController for each input element.

```
function MainController($scope) {
  this.paste = function() {
    var value = this.pasteValue;
    var inputs = angular.element(document.getElementById('values')).find('input');
    angular.forEach(inputs, function(input) {
      var ngModel = angular.element(input).controller('ngModel');
      ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
      input.value = value;
    });
  };
}
```

### 2

The second solution is more the angular way and uses an addtional directive that whatches on paste data.

```
function setView() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      setView : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch('setView', function(newValue) {
        if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
          elem.val(newValue);
          ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
        }
      })
    }

  }  
}

function MainController($scope) {
  this.paste = function() {
    var value = this.pasteValue;
    this.values.forEach(function(v) { v.i = value });
  };
}
```

The view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in main.values">
      <input ng-model="value.v" twice set-view="value.i"/> {{value.i}}({{value.v}})
    </li>
</ul>
```